# Understanding big O notation for exponent functions

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I have been trying to understand big O notation for log functions. Consider the following two functions:
$$f(x) = log_2x  $$
$$g(x) = log_3x  $$

Now, with a little bit of research that I did, I realized that
$$f(x)∈O(g(x))$$
$$g(x)∈O(f(x))$$

because the same logs with different bases differ from each other by a constant and hence the above two points make sense.

Now I am trying to understand the behavior of the following two functions:
$$f(x)= n^5$$
$$g(x)= 5^n$$

Can someone help me reason as to how do I go about understanding the big O notation for these two functions like I did for the log function

Comment: $g$ grows much faster than $f$ in the second example (specifically, $\frac{g(n)}{f(n)} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$).

Comment: If youre just trying to compare the two you need to do a little analysis. Youll see one of the derivatives is much greater than the other for large n.

Comment: since g grows much faster than f, is it g(x)∈O(f(x)) or the other way around..i guess I really don't know what ∈ means ?

Comment: @Algebraic..how would I do that ?

Comment: Read the definition of big O carefully.  $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ means $f(n)$ is bounded above by a constant times $g(n)$, so $g$ can grow much faster than $f$, but $f$ cannot grow faster than $g$.

Answer (score 2):

A crucial point is that anything (greater than $1$) to the $n$ power grows *much* faster (eventually) than any power of $n$.  In your example, then
$$f(n) \in O(g(n))\\
g(n) \not \in O(f(n))$$
This is still true if $f(n)=n^{1000000}, g(n)=1.0000001^n$ but it takes longer for the eventual domination to set in.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) \in O(g(x))$ if $|f(x)| < C|g(x)|$ for large enough $x$, for some $C$.

Note that the function $h(x)=x^{1/x}$ has positive derivative for $x\in (0,e)$ and negative derivative for $x\in (e,\infty)$, so you have for large $n$, (for any $ n\gt 5$) $$n^{1/n} \lt 5^{1/5} \implies n^5 \lt 5^n$$
which settles the fact that $f(x)\in O(g(x))$ in your example.

However, with $C=5^{1/5}$, $$\begin{aligned}\dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)}=\dfrac{5^n}{n^5}=\left(\dfrac{5^{1/5}}{n^{1/n}}\right)^{5n}=\lambda \implies \ln\lambda&=5n\ln C-5n\ln(n^{1/n})\\ &=5C'n-\dfrac{5n}{n}\ln n\\  &=5C'n-5\ln n \\\implies  \ln\lambda&= 5n\left(C'-\dfrac{\ln n}{\ln(n+1)}\dfrac{\ln(n+1)}{n}\right) \end{aligned}$$
Now as $n\to\infty$ the term in the brackets has a finite limit but 
$5n\to\infty\implies \ln \lambda \to \infty \stackrel{n\to\infty}{\implies} \dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)}=\lambda \to \infty$, as mentioned in the first comment, which in the language of analysis, means that for any $M\in \Bbb{R}$, $$\dfrac{g(n)}{f(n)}>M \  \text{for large enough $n$}\\ \implies \text{for no $M'\in\Bbb{R}$,} \ g(n)< M'f(n) \implies g(n) \notin O(f(n))$$
You might consider checking out [this related answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1364491/5646116).